# rvm requirements fails due to unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to get rvm up and running on ubuntu 14.04 and having a tough time figuring out why I can't meet the dependencies. I have done multiple `apt-get update && spt-get upgrades` but still having this error.

```
zachs@Ranger:~$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system......
Installing required packages: gawk, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, libgdbm-dev, bison, libffi-dev.....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libgdbm-dev bison libffi-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /home/zachs/.rvm/log/1452398643/package_install_gawk_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3_libgdbm-dev_bison_libffi-dev.log
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libffi-dev : Depends: libffi6 (= 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12) but 3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libyaml-dev : Depends: libyaml-0-2 (= 0.1.4-3ubuntu3) but 0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
+ return 100
+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

My guess is that I need to install the ubuntu versions of these packages but why is `apt-get update` not catching them?

I believe I have installed rvm correctly because I get this response:

```
$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
```

Attempts to install the unmet dependencies also fails:

```
zachs@Ranger:~$ sudo apt-get install libffi6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libffi6 is already the newest version.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I had to use aptitude directly to install libffi-dev:

```
sudo aptitude install libffi-dev
```

Then it prompted asking me if I want to choose the default option to leave libffi-dev not installed. Choose "n" (no). The next option should specify that libffi6 will be downgraded and libffi-dev will be installed. Choose "y" (yes).

This resulted in libffi-dev being installed. You may have to choose "n" until it gives you the option that downgrades libffi6 and installs libffi-dev.

Note that you need to have aptitude installed to do this.